# QBasic Vs. QuickBASIC

Tags: qbasic, quickbasic

I want to learn "old school" programming. A friend suggested Q BASIC.
But another person told me Quick Basic. I want to practice programming
in the OLD Dos operating system.

What is the difference between the two Q Basic and Quick Basic?

Comment: Did you try using Google to read about both to see what the difference is?

Answer (score 6):

Differences between QBasic and QuickBasic:
QBasic is the slimmed-down version of QuickBasic.
Compared to QuickBasic, QBasic is limited as it lacks a compiler.
Therefore QBasic cannot be used to produce executables (.exe files).
The source code (usually files with .bas extension) can only be executed immediately by the built-in QBasic interpreter.

Furthermore, QuickBasic has a more extensive command set than QBasic.